# Fail to override Assembly Merge Strategy in multi-jvm node test

Tags: merge, sbt, scalatest, sbt-assembly

I am having trouble overriding the merge strategy for a dependency.

The problem stems from the cassandra dependency rely on separate netty modules

```
val akkaCassandra = "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-cassandra" % "0.17"
```

If I run the graph-dependency, it outputs:

```
  | +-io.netty:netty-handler:4.0.33.Final
[info]     |   +-io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.33.Final
[info]     |   | +-io.netty:netty-common:4.0.33.Final
[info]     |   |
[info]     |   +-io.netty:netty-codec:4.0.33.Final
[info]     |   | +-io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.33.Final
[info]     |   |   +-io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.33.Final
[info]     |   |     +-io.netty:netty-common:4.0.33.Final
[info]     |   |
[info]     |   +-io.netty:netty-transport:4.0.33.Final
[info]     |     +-io.netty:netty-buffer:4.0.33.Final
[info]     |       +-io.netty:netty-common:4.0.33.Final
```

According to this discussion, its best to just define a merge strategy as a solution:

https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!msg/spark-connector-user/5muNwRaCJnU/sIHYh6PFEwAJ

> Netty unfortunately has timing dependent markers in each
>   io.versions.properties file in the metainfUntitled.jpg
>
> This means the various components included all have different
>   timestamps which is why everything is breaking. Unfortunately this is
>   the underlying C* driver's dep, we could I guess exclude these netty
>   modules from the driver and include netty-all in the connector instead
>   but that seems like overkill.
>
> I think just fixing the application build file is still the best
>   solution.

According to this, the ability to override should be implemented:

https://github.com/typesafehub/sbt-multi-jvm/issues/22

> Nested assembly config should be exposed for customization along with
>   the other multijvm keys so that users can solve these issues.
>
> i think that PR #19 will enable this functionality. the change at
>   msfrank@fe862ff#diff-ad54d47177586fbaf474e402dd1b3dc5R137 will pass
>   through the merge strategy defined with settings key
>   (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly) as long as the file is not one of
>   *.class, *.txt, or NOTICE, which are hardcoded merge strategies

.

But when I run

```
sbt:multi-node-test

lazy val test = Project(id = "core-tests", base = file("./modules/core/tests"))
  .settings(SbtMultiJvm.multiJvmSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.coreTests,
    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case x if x.endsWith("META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties") ⇒ MergeStrategy.first
    },
    compile in MultiJvm <<= (compile in MultiJvm) triggeredBy (compile in Test),
    parallelExecution in Test := false,
    executeTests in Test <<= (executeTests in Test, executeTests in MultiJvm) map {
      case (testResults, multiNodeResults) ⇒
        val overall =
          if (testResults.overall.id < multiNodeResults.overall.id)
            multiNodeResults.overall
          else
            testResults.overall
        Tests.Output(overall,
          testResults.events ++ multiNodeResults.events,
          testResults.summaries ++ multiNodeResults.summaries)
    },
    licenses := Seq(("CC0", url("http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0"))),
    Settings.levelDb, Settings.test)
```

it still refused to use the merge strategy, I defined.

```
[error] 1 error was encountered during merge

[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last core-tests/multi-jvm:assembly' for the full output.

[error] (core-tests/multi-jvm:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:

[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-handler/jars/netty-handler-4.0.33.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties

[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-buffer/jars/netty-buffer-4.0.33.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties

[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-common/jars/netty-common-4.0.33.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties

[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-transport/jars/netty-transport-4.0.33.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties

[error] ~/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec/jars/netty-codec-4.0.33.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.propertie
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for you, because in your code you override settings for the `sbt-assembly` task.

What you need to do instead, is to override settings for the `sbt-assembly` in context of `sbt-multi-jvm` plugin.

You can do it this way:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly in MultiJvm := {
  case x if x.endsWith("META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties") ⇒ MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These files have different content, I see no much harm in concatenating them:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly  := {
  case PathList("META-INF", "io.netty.versions.properties") =>
    MergeStrategy.concat
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
}
```

Then see content:

```
unzip -p YOUR_ASSEBMBLY.jar "META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties"
```